# Laravel: Slow download using Response::download

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so I have a large (1.7mb) jpg file that I want to allow users to download as a screen wallpaper. I am using the following:

```
/**
* getWallpaper
* Download the wallpaper in jpg format from above web root
* 
* @return file
*/
public function getWallpaper()
{
$file = "../downloads/myfile.jpg";

$headers = array('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

return Response::download($file, 'myfile.jpg', $headers);
}
```

This works really fast on my local dev server, but takes around 14 seconds for the browser download dialogue box to appear on my production server.
Any ideas? Could be a setting miss-match at the server level, if so what settings should I be looking at?
Thanks for any help.
Ollie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anybody is having the same issue - for me it turned out to be a network connection problem.

On my work connection, I still get a long delay before the download dialogue appears, whereas at home it appears almost instantly. I have no idea why though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here but you could try setting the attachment and content type header and then instantly call `flush()` to send that information to the client so it opens the dialog.

```
public function getWallpaper(){
    $file = "../downloads/myfile.jpg";

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.jpg"');

    flush();

    return Response::download($file, 'myfile.jpg');
}
```

In my opinion it feels a bit hacky (and redundant, since we're setting headers that are then again set in `Response::download`, but if it works you could maybe extend the `Response` class or something.

Comment: Thanks but no dice - still taking 12-14 seconds for the download dialogue to show up.

Comment: Hmmm... Can you try it on another server? I'm wondering if your local dev server is the only thing that works as expected or if your current production server is the only one having a problem...

Comment: I might be able to set something up on another server - but I have been playing around and have some more news: If I try to do this with a pdf, it works as expected, i.e. download dialogue shows up immediately on click. However, I've also noticed that .zip files have the same slow behaviour as jpg. Does that give you any clues?

Comment: I suppose all the files are about the same size?

Comment: OK, It's got to be the server - I just threw the same .zip file up on another box and it works great. I also tested on another domain on the production server and got the same time lag. Will take it up with the hosting providers. edit: Yep - same file size

Comment: I am using the Storage::download. However the effect was the same. Slow response time. Just adding the flush() before the Storage::download solved the problem. No idea why, though.